# How to add TestNG plug-in into Eclipse IDE 3.4.0?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, plugins, testng

I have Eclipse IDE 3.4.0 version and i need to work with selenium 2.52 and TestNG.

Can anyone please provide your thoughts on adding TestNG plugin with **Eclipse IDE 3.4.0** version?

Thanks 
Karunagara Pandi G

Comment: Can you check here? https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/testng-eclipse and https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/93

Comment: Eclipse IDE 3.4.0 has been released June 2008. Some plug-ins may require a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://testng.org/doc/download.html):

> Eclipse 3.x is NOT supported any more, please update your Eclipse to 4.2 or above.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on TEstNG webpage "Eclipse 4.2 and above is required"

Java 1.7+ is required for running the TestNG for Eclipse plugin.

Eclipse 4.2 and above is required. Eclipse 3.x is NOT supported any more, please update your Eclipse to 4.2 or above.

You can use either the Eclipse Marketplace or the update site:

Refer this http://testng.org/doc/download.html